# How does HList.foldRight look for implicits when used in the implementation of a type class?

Tags: scala, typeclass, scalaz, shapeless

I am newbie at using Shapeless, and I am experimenting with Shapeless for automatic type class generation and  folding over HLists. 
My goal is to render a `HList` as `(a, b, c, d)` using a typeclass implementation of scalaz.Show

My first step was to  experiment in the REPL with the following code

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist._

object prettyPrint extends Poly2 {
  implicit def defaultCase[A] = at((a:A, z:String)=>s", ${a.toString}$z")
}

def print[H, T<:HList](f: H :: T)(implicit folder:RightFolder.Aux[H :: T, String, prettyPrint.type, String]) = {
  f.foldRight("")(prettyPrint)
}

val f = 1::'a::2::'b::HNil
val res = s"(${f.head}${print(f.tail)})" // Results res: String = (1, 'a, 2, 'b)
```

After this I implemented the following method in my implementation of `LabelledTypeClassCompanion[...]`. Unfortunately, this code does not compile because the compiler is complaining about missing implicits, even though I can't tell what the difference is between the code in the REPL and the code below. My Question is what is the problem in the code below and how can I fix it?

```
def showFold[H, T<:HList](f: H::T)(implicit folder:RightFolder.Aux[ H::T, String, prettyPrint.type, String]) = {
  f.foldRight("")(prettyPrint)
}

override def product[H, T <: HList](name: String, ch: ScalazShow[H], ct: ScalazShow[T]): ScalazShow[H :: T] = {
  new ScalazShow[H :: T] {
    override def shows(ft: (H :: T)): String = {
     showFold(ft) // This does not compile
    }

  }
}
```

Error:(49, 18) could not find implicit value for parameter folder: shapeless.ops.hlist.RightFolder.Aux[shapeless.::[H,T],String,com.fpinscala.ninetynine.prettyPrint.type,String]
         showFold(ft) // This does not compile

Below is the complete implementation

```
package com.fpinscala.ninetynine

import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.RightFolder

import scalaz.{Show => ScalazShow}

object prettyPrint extends Poly2 {
  implicit def defaultCase[A]:this.Case.Aux[A, String, String] = at[A, String]{
    (a,z) => s", $a$z"
  }
}


object ShowImpl extends LabelledTypeClassCompanion[ScalazShow] {

  implicit def symbolShow : ScalazShow[Symbol] = new ScalazShow[Symbol] {
    override def shows(f: Symbol): String = f.toString()
  }

  implicit def intShow : ScalazShow[Int] = new ScalazShow[Int] {
    override def shows(f: Int): String = f.toString
  }

  override val typeClass: LabelledTypeClass[ScalazShow] = new LabelledTypeClass[ScalazShow] {

    override def coproduct[L, R <: Coproduct](name: String, cl: => ScalazShow[L], cr: => ScalazShow[R]): ScalazShow[L :+: R] = new ScalazShow[L :+: R] {
      override def shows(lr: (L :+: R)): String = lr match {
        case Inl(l) => cl.shows(l)
        case Inr(r) => cr.shows(r)
      }
    }

    override def emptyCoproduct: ScalazShow[CNil] = new ScalazShow[CNil] {
      override def shows(f: CNil): String = ""
    }


    def showFold[H, T<:HList](f: H::T)(implicit folder:RightFolder.Aux[ H::T, String, prettyPrint.type, String]) = {
      f.foldRight("")(prettyPrint)
    }

    override def product[H, T <: HList](name: String, ch: ScalazShow[H], ct: ScalazShow[T]): ScalazShow[H :: T] = {
      new ScalazShow[H :: T] {
        override def shows(ft: (H :: T)): String = {
         showFold(ft) // This does not compile 
        }

      }
    }

    override def project[F, G](instance: => ScalazShow[G], to: (F) => G, from: (G) => F): ScalazShow[F] = new ScalazShow[F] {
      override def shows(f: F): String = instance.shows(to(f))
    }

    override def emptyProduct: ScalazShow[HNil] = new ScalazShow[HNil] {
      override def shows(f: HNil): String = ""
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think of a type class constraint as a way to carry some information about a type from a concrete context to a generic context (moving backward through the call stack). In this case you actually really do need that `RightFolder` instance if you want to write your implementation this way, but the method signatures in `LabelledTypeClass` don't allow you to carry that information through, so you're out of luck (the basic idea is possible, though—you just need a slightly different approach).

## Update

I just realized I misread your question slightly—because you were using the `TypeClass` type class I assumed you wanted instances for case classes and sealed trait hierarchies as well as hlists and coproducts. My answer gives you all of these (just like `TypeClass` would), so you can write this:

```
scala> (123 :: "abc" :: HNil).shows
res2: String = (123, abc)
```

As well as the case class and sealed trait examples I give below. If you don't want case classes and sealed traits you can just remove the `genericShow` definition.

## Why the difference between concrete and generic contexts

Here's a simpler case to start with. Suppose we want to use `Show` to print a value twice. We can do something like this:

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val x: Int = 123
x: Int = 123

scala> s"${ x.shows }${ x.shows }"
res0: String = 123123
```

Here `x` has a concrete type, and when we call `.shows` on it, the compiler will try to find an instance of `Show` for that concrete type. Scalaz provides a `Show[Int]`, so everything works just fine and we get the result we want.

Next we can try writing a generic version:

```
def toStringTwice[X](x: X): String = s"${ x.shows }${ x.shows }"
```

But the compiler will complain:

```
<console>:18: error: value shows is not a member of type parameter X
       def toStringTwice[X](x: X): String = s"${ x.shows }${ x.shows }"
                                                               ^
```

This is because the compiler can't prove that `X` has a `Show` instance, since it doesn't know anything at all about `X`. You could just write a bunch of overloaded concrete methods:

```
scala> def toStringTwice(x: String): String = s"${ x.shows }${ x.shows }"
toStringTwice: (x: String)String

scala> def toStringTwice(x: Int): String = s"${ x.shows }${ x.shows }"
toStringTwice: (x: Int)String

...
```

But this is exactly the kind of annoying boilerplate that type classes are designed to save you from. Instead of enumerating all the types you have `Show` instances for, you can abstract over them by providing the compiler with exactly as much information as it needs:

```
scala> def toStringTwice[X: Show](x: X): String = s"${ x.shows }${ x.shows }"
toStringTwice: [X](x: X)(implicit evidence$1: scalaz.Show[X])String
```

Now you can call it with an `Int`, or anything else that has a `Show` instance:

```
scala> toStringTwice(123)
res2: String = 123123
```

What you can't do is call it with another unconstrained generic type:

```
def toStringFourTimes[X](x: X): String = s"${ toStringTwice(x) * 2 }"
```

Instead you have to add the constraint again:

```
scala> def toStringFourTimes[X: Show](x: X): String = s"${ toStringTwice(x) * 2 }"
toStringFourTimes: [X](x: X)(implicit evidence$1: scalaz.Show[X])String
```

And so on—you have to carry along the `Show` constraint all the way until you've got a concrete type. You can only use `toStringTwice` in two ways: on a concrete type that has a `Show` instance, or on a generic type that has a `Show` constraint.

Note that none of the above is Shapeless-specific—this is simply the way type classes work.

## One possible fix

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to me like a very good use case for `LabelledTypeClass`, since the desired instance doesn't really fit the way of building up instances that the `TypeClass` type classes support. You could probably do it but I don't really want to try.

There's also an issue in the way your `prettyPrint` works—it's not actually using the `Show` instance for `A` (there's not even one to use), but is instead calling the horrible universal `toString`.

Here's a quick first draft of how I'd probably write this:

```
import scalaz.Show, scalaz.Scalaz._
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.coproduct.Folder
import shapeless.ops.hlist.RightReducer

object prettyPrint2 extends Poly2 {
  implicit def defaultCase[A: Show]: Case.Aux[A, String, String] =
    at[A, String]((a, z) => s"$a, $z")
}

object prettyPrint extends Poly1 {
  implicit def defaultCase[A: Show]: Case.Aux[A, String] = at[A](_.shows)
}

implicit def hlistShow[L <: HList](implicit
  reducer: RightReducer.Aux[L, prettyPrint2.type, String]
): Show[L] = Show.shows(l => "(" + l.reduceRight(prettyPrint2) + ")")

implicit def coproductShow[C <: Coproduct](implicit
  folder: Folder.Aux[prettyPrint.type, C, String]
): Show[C] = Show.shows(_.fold(prettyPrint))

implicit def genericShow[A, R](implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[A, R],
  reprShow: Show[R]
): Show[A] = reprShow.contramap(gen.to)
```

And then:

```
scala> Foo(123, "abc").shows
res0: String = (123, abc)

scala> (Foo(123, "abc"): Base).shows
res1: String = (123, abc)
```

You may run into corner cases involving nested case classes, etc. that don't work because of compiler bugs (see my [slides here](http://meta.plasm.us/slides/scalaworld/) about generic derivation in Scala for some details), but this approach should more or less do what you want.

Comment: I had a suspicion that my approach was wrong. Your answer confirmed it! I did run into errors where the compiler started complaining about divergent implicit expansion when using nested classes like you said it would . I'll go over your slides to try and resolve that.

Comment: @HaroonKhan It might be as simple as putting a `Lazy` around the `Generic` instance in `genericShow`.